# URL generation weird in Playframework

Tags: playframework

I am facing a wierd issue regarding in URL generation in Playframework.

Here is my code snippet in template:

> @{Rooms.list(customerId?:customerId, location?:location, roomId?:roomId)}

Obviousely I wanna to generate a the URL like this:

> /rooms/list?customer=1&location=asdf&roomId=1

But finally I got this:

> `/rooms/list?customer=1&amp;location=asdf&amp;roomId=1`

I traced down the play source code and found this in "GroovyTemplate":

```
if (template.template.name.endsWith(".html") || template.template.name.endsWith(".xml")) {
    def.url = def.url.replace("&", "&amp;");
}
```

Could anybody tell what's the purpose of this replacement? How can I get my URL correctly?

Thanks

Comment: which version of Play are you running?

Comment: Hi @Codemwnci, I am using head of master branch in git repository, should be 1.1.1. And I've checked the code history, this piece of code has been existed since 1.0 period.

Comment: you could try posting that question at play's google group, they have a really active and helful community... -> http://groups.google.com/group/play-framework

Comment: I do post my question there before but no helpful response. http://groups.google.com/group/play-framework/browse_thread/thread/f3107c0f92009d3c/06b27f2262c36984#06b27f2262c36984

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not sure if this answers your question, but you could try the following:

```
@{Rooms.list().add("customerId", customerId).add("location", location).add("roomId", roomId)}
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution works perfectly. But I still have concern about the URL generation mechanism.

Comment: well, don't hesitate to ask at play's google groups http://groups.google.com/group/play-framework, or even better, have a look at the source code... use the source, luke!

Comment: yes, probably you should ask what you are doing before was correct or not.